# create a json key for query in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to pass an object in a link but i dont want it to look like a query: `"?foo='bar'"`

I want it to be less informative and look like a token:
`"/dfjvn23bkjb2kbkjb2khbkhb2"` and then decode it in react.

I dont need it to be secure or something tho...

I have already tried searching and i saw some **crypt** or **jwt** but i think its overkill.. and even that we can generate a jwt from react...

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Base64 Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64) which is built-in in JS:

```js
const content = JSON.stringify({ someKey: "This is some data..." });
const urlAppendix = btoa(content)
console.log(urlAppendix); // prints "eyJzb21lS2V5IjoiVGhpcyBpcyBzb21lIGRhdGEuLi4ifQ=="

// .. decode later
console.log(JSON.parse(atob(urlAppendix))); // prints the object
```